# Bash - Start a new instance of a command in another terminal seperate from your current terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, watch

I have a simple bash script (test.sh) set up like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=("$@")
if [[ ( ${args[0]} = "check_capture" ) ]]; then
  watch -n 1 'ls -lag /home/user/capture0'
  watch -n 1 'ls -lag /home/user/capture1'
  watch -n 1 'ls -lag /home/user/capture2' 
  exit
fi
```

Files are continuously being written to these target locations capture 0, capture 1, and capture 3. I want to be able to watch these directories using ls command continuously on 3 seperate terminals, and once I run this script (test.sh) from the current terminal, I want it to exit.

Right now it is blocked by each wait, which I know is a blocking bash command waiting for user input control-c. Is there a way I can have the 3 watch commands be executed in seperate terminals then reach the exit statement?

Comment: which terminal are you using?

Comment: just the regular terminal in rhel7 - xterm.

Answer (score 3):

You can start several instances of the terminal in background, each one running a command, like this:

```
if [[ ... ]]; then
    xterm -e 'watch -n 1 "ls -lag /home/user/capture0"' &
    xterm -e 'watch -n 1 "ls -lag /home/user/capture1"' &
    ...
    exit
fi
```

Check `man xterm`:

> **`-e program [ arguments ... ]`**
>
> This  option  specifies the program (and its command line arguments) to be run in the xterm window.  It also sets  the window title and icon name to be the basename of the program being executed if neither -T nor -n are given on
>   the command line.  This must be the last option on the command line.

The same option works also for `xfce-terminal` and `gnome-terminal`.

In addition, `xterm` (and others) also support setting the title of the window, position, size (called geometry), colors, fonts, and *many, many* other features.