# opening multiple terminals with gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I would like to run a .sh file that launches several terminals in specific folders, each of these executing a specific command.

How would I do this using "gnome-terminal" ?

I checked this page "http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html" but I'm still stucked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple lines like this in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir1 --command './some-command1' &
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir2 --command './some-command2' &
```

very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45381796/404556).

Note the use of `&` to run the terminal in background. Other options should be self-explanatory.